# Bootstrap 3 active tab doesn't show when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Question:
When I load my page, the active tab doesnt show anything. It only does when I go to a different tab and then back. When I reload the page, the 'active' tab is empty again.

So,
When I load the page, the 'home' tab is empty. If I go to 'prijslijst' (prijslijst is filled correctly) and then back to 'home', 'home' is filled. If I were to reload the page, 'home' is empty yet again.

HTML:

```
<section class="no-padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper-selector">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Woningselector</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#prijslijst" aria-controls="prijslijst" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Prijslijst</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <!--Selector Tab-->
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active" id="home">
                    <div class="selector" style="position: relative;">
                        <div id="mapwrapper">
                            <img id="Woningselector" alt="Woningselector" usemap="#Woningselector"/>
                        </div>
                        <map name="Woningselector" id="mapWoningselector"></map>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Prijslijst Tab-->
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="prijslijst">
                    {include file="componenten/prijslijst.tpl"}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the the `HTML` using `browser console` & see what happen when you back to first tab (*click on first tab*).

You need to use `active in` instead of `active`.

```
<section class="no-padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper-selector">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                  <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Woningselector</a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#prijslijst" aria-controls="prijslijst" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Prijslijst</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <!--Selector Tab-->
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
                    <div class="selector" style="position: relative;">
                        <div id="mapwrapper">
                            <img id="Woningselector" alt="Woningselector" usemap="#Woningselector"/>
                        </div>
                        <map name="Woningselector" id="mapWoningselector"></map>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Prijslijst Tab-->
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="prijslijst">
                    {include file="componenten/prijslijst.tpl"}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is the difference between active and active in?

Comment: @Greeshma `in` is necessary here because of `fade` class, if you check the source _`bootstrap.css`_ you will see that `fade` class change the `opacity` to 0, so we need `in` class to change the `opacity` back to 1, to make content visible.